# how to optimize illustrator artwork in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash, cpu-usage

I'm working on a flash project that incorporates a lot of artwork done in Illustrator CS4. I've been copy-pasting directly from Illustrator into Flash, and I add some animations as well. Final file is going to be a one single swf file which will be a part of UI for an application and .net will be the core for this. But now flash becomes unusable slow to respond for actions. 
My machine is a fast i7 with 6gb of RAM, so I don't think that's the issue. We are going to use this file with dual core atom processors. Does anyone have ideas for alternative importing techniques, optimizations within illustrator, anything at all that will make this more manageable?
Thanks

Comment: is Flash CS4 becoming slow or is it the movie produced and being played through flash player that's becoming slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the stuff you're pasting from AI is vector, Flash becomes very slow when trying to render all of those objects on the screen. Under the View menu, select Preview Mode, then Fast. The images will look jaggy on the screen, but the interface will be snappier.

Comment: thank you very much for the response wpjmurray, this help me a lot. will this effect in compiled swf?

Comment: No, it won't affect the compiled swf at all, it's just there to make the interface faster when you have a lot of items visible at once.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to save your vector file in EPS10 format. In order to reduce the EPS file size it should be enough to reduce the linear dimensions of our artwork. It can be done with the help of Selection Tool (V) or command Scale (Object > Transform > Scale).